# MVC5 to use custom membership or my own implemenation?

Tags: asp.net-membership, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm starting a new project and intending(I actually started implementation) to use MVC 5 and most recent microsoft technologies. In my DB, I have my own table to manage user accounts and storing passwords and I have no problem or complexity doing that.

But(*and there always but*), most tutorials I see on MVC use `.NET Membership`. Every tutorial I read to learn about the new fetures is using it. This gives me a feeling that I should too be using it or at least write a custom implementation of it.

Am I looking to it wrongly? Am I missing something here? Do I need to take the development process little bit slower?

I really ***confused*** and I'm not sure which path to take specially I'm still at the start of my project.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using Asp Identity 2 which replaces the old Asp Membership, with the account functionality scaffolded when you create a new MVC 5 Web application. It gives you heaps of functionality straight out of the box.

Of course, it depends on your requirements, but this is a pretty robust way to get started. It easily allows you to intergrate other OAuth providers like Facebook etc.

Here are some helpful resources:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/06/27/introducing-asp-net-identity-membership-system-for-asp-net-applications.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/16/customizing-profile-information-in-asp-net-identity-in-vs-2013-templates.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj200620.aspx

You can map your current user table to the IdentityUser if they follow the same structure.
http://coderdiaries.com/2014/01/29/custom-table-names-for-asp-net-identity/